# omxplayer cannot play yuv444p?

Tags: video, omxplayer, ffmpeg

I have encoded videos from image sequences with ffmpeg, some play in omxplayer, some don't. Looking at them with `-I` shows they use different pixel format, the one that works uses yuv420p, the one that doesn't yuv444p (another difference is that it says "Predictive").

Works:

```
$ omxplayer --no-osd -I works.mp4 
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'works.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.41.100
  Duration: 00:07:38.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6958 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1024x1024 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 6958 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Video codec omx-h264 width 1024 height 1024 profile 100 fps 25.000000
Subtitle count: 0, state: off, index: 1, delay: 0
V:PortSettingsChanged: 1024x1024@25.00 interlace:0 deinterlace:0 anaglyph:0 par:1.00 display:0 layer:0 alpha:255 aspectMode:0
```

Doesn't show video:

```
$ omxplayer --no-osd -I broken.mp4 
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'broken.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.41.100
  Duration: 00:00:57.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1432 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p, 1024x1024, 1429 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Video codec omx-h264 width 1024 height 1024 profile 244 fps 25.000000
Subtitle count: 0, state: off, index: 1, delay: 0
```

Is this a limitation of omxplayer? Can I use a high quality encoding such as yuv444?

---

**Edit:** [Here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) is the ffmpeg document that lists the "profiles" that one could enforce. Is there any statement which profiles omxplayer does *not* support (apparently high444 is one)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The problem

libx264 supports multiple "pixel formats", so `ffmpeg` will automatically attempt to use whatever most closely matches the input. However, some players can't decode anything other than `yuv(j)420p`.

## The solution

Add `-vf format=yuv420p` (or the alias `-pix_fmt yuv420p`) output options to your encoding command.

See [Encoding for Dumb Players](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#Encodingfordumbplayers) in the link you provided.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I can confirm that adding `-pix_fmt yuv420p` works.